# Event ID: 2019, Empty nonpaged pool

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I need to troubleshoot Event ID: 2019, Empty nonpaged pool errors.  I have found a lot of articles, like 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177415

It sounds that debugging driver-leaks is a labor-intensive affair.  Before I dive into it, I would welcome some hands-on tips from people who did something similar recently.

TIA,
Radim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one time this was a problem for me (thanks bad HP/Compaq server NIC driver!) I found that following the procedure in that article wasn't really all that bad, and quickly zeroed-in on the cuplrit. I'd recommend giving it a shot-- it's really not that bad. Once I had pool tagging enabled and let the machine run for a couple of days I had my answer in PoolMon in just a few minutes.

Edit: That's a pretty old version of iaStor.Sys. I can't find any other reports of nonpaged pool leaks with iaStor.sys, but it's possible.

The current version of iaStor.sys is an "8" version. I'd consider pulling down an update from Intel (http://downloadcenter.intel.com/filter_results.aspx?strTypes=all&ProductID=2101&OSFullName=Windows*+XP+Professional&lang=eng&strOSs=44&submit=Go%21). I can't tell you that there isn't some potential risk in doing such a driver upgrade, but it ought to go smoothly. Decide based on your tolerance for risk and your level of backup of the data if you should proceed with an upgrade.

I'm curious about that "xns2" pool tag. You say that's from USBSTOR.SYS? Did you find that with the "Parse a Driver for Memory Tags" function in PoolMon.exe?

Comment: 1) I found nice program, PoolTag.exe from www.osr.com.  Like pooplmon.exe, but w GUI, easy to save a log, etc.

2) What leaks is tag STOR:

   OSR's PoolTag Reporter
   Sat Jun 27 10:33:24 2009

   1332 tags shown
Active filters: (none)
PTAG    PAG/NON   # Allocs    # Frees  Alloc-Free       Used
----    -------  ---------  ---------  ----------  ---------
xns2      NON            7          0          7    40341504
Stor      NON        88905       1387      87518    26021824

Hard to identify the offending driver, either iaStor.sys or usbstor.sys. My bet is INTEL iaStor.sys, ver 5.5.0.1035

Comment: iaStor.sys is the storage driver for my on-board RAID-1. I am booting from this RAID, I am not sure what I should do next.

Comment: I tried 2007-vintage poolmon.exe.  It indicates that iastor.sys and usbstor.sys might be innocent.  The offender is:
Stor Nonp     169527 (  13)       950 (   0)   168577 49377328 (  3744)    292 Unknown Driver

BTW: xns2 is my Philips webcam. It does take 40MB but it seems to behave ok.  As far as iastor.sys, this is 2004-04 PC, my version of iastor is the one recommneded by INTEL.

Comment: @radim: Did you get it resolved? What was the culprit?